# Como pegar o valor de POST e salvar no banco

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde amigos, não estou conseguindo salvar o segundo *INSERT* no banco, pois quando eu salvo, ele vai como array, como posso resolver esse problema?

## Imagem da View:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Imagem do Banco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Código

```
$nome_plano = trim($_POST["nome_plano"]);
    $quemcadastrou = $userRow['nome_funcionario'];
    
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $conn->beginTransaction();
      $conn->exec("INSERT INTO plano (nome_plano, quemcadastrou, data_hora_cadastro) VALUES ('$nome_plano', '$quemcadastrou', NOW())");
        $lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();
    
        foreach($_POST['informacao'] as $informacao){    
                $parcelaplano[''] = trim($_POST['parcelaplano']);
                $porcentagem[] = trim($_POST['porcentagem']);
                $conn->exec("INSERT INTO inform_plano (id_plano, parcelaplano, porcentagem) VALUES ('$lastid', '$parcelaplano', '$porcentagem')");
                print_r($informacao);
    }
    // commit the transaction
    $conn->commit();
     echo "<h1>CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO</h1>";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    // roll back the transaction if something failed
    $conn->rollback();
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente as informações que você precisa gravar estão na variável `$informacao`.

Tente substituir as seguintes linhas:

```
$parcelaplano[''] = trim($_POST['parcelaplano']);
$porcentagem[] = trim($_POST['porcentagem']);
```

Por:

```
$parcelaplano = trim($informacao['parcelaplano']);
$porcentagem = trim($informacao['porcentagem']);
```

Comment: Deu certo, muto obrigado amigo...

Answer (score 0):

Você esta definindo um array neste momento do código:

```
 $parcelaplano[''] = trim($_POST['parcelaplano']);
 $porcentagem[] = trim($_POST['porcentagem']);
```

Tente modificar estas duas linhas acima, por estas abaixo:

```
 $parcelaplano = trim($_POST['parcelaplano']);
 $porcentagem = trim($_POST['porcentagem']);
```

Comment: Coloquei, mas nenhuma informação foi inserida no banco, até o nome do Array sumiu, foi apenas o id_plano

Comment: Faz um var_dump para verificar o valor destas variaveis: $_POST['parcelaplano'] e $_POST['porcentagem'], provavelmente eles estao vazios.

Comment: Realmente, eles estão vindo: null, como faço pra concertar isso? E porque as informações do Array na View estão sendo visualizadas?